How glm::translate works?
While debugging a videogame in OpenGl C++ I printed the transformation/translate matrix and show me something like this:
1 0 0 0

0 1 0 0

0 0 1 0

tx ty tz 1

​
but I think it should be:
​
1 0 0 tx

0 1 0 ty

0 0 1 tz

0 0 0 1

This is the code:
glm::mat4 transform;
transform = glm::mat4();

unsigned int transformLoc = glGetUniformLocation(this->shaderProgram, "transform");
transform = glm::translate(transform, glm::vec3(5.0, 0.0, 1.0));
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
        std::cout << transform[i][j] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

And prints:
1 0 0 0

0 1 0 0

0 0 1 0

5 0 1 1


"Matrix types store their values in column-major order"

Thanks! I was trying to figure what was happening. vec3() is a column, not a row (
as i thought)

Maybe, operator[] of glm::mat4 returns column vector ( not row vector).
